# A short exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have this proposition, and I don't understand how to do to obtain the short exact sequence:

[image]

where axiom 4 is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $i_*$ is injective, the images of the boundary maps $\partial$ are zero (by exactness of the sequence given in axiom 4). The exactness of the sequence also means that $j_*$ is surjective. Hence the long exact sequence given by axiom 4 breaks up into short exact sequences

$$0\overset{\partial}{\to} H_k(A)\overset{i_*}{\to}H_k(X)\overset{j_*}{\to}H_k(X,A)\overset{\partial}{\to}0$$

Comment: because $Im~ \partial =0$ then $H_{k+1}(X,A)=0$ ? $\partial: H_{k+1}(X,A)\rightarrow H_k(A)$

Comment: Since $\text{im }\partial =0$, it follows that $\text{im }j_*=\ker \partial = H_k(X,A)$. That's why $j_*$ is surjective.

Comment: So why we have $0\overset{\partial}{\to} H_k(A)$ why $0$ ? please

Comment: Perhaps the map really shouldn't be called $\partial$. The first $0$ is there merely to show that $i_*$ is in fact injective.

Comment: don't understand why the first 0

Comment: You want to represent the fact that $i_*:H_k(A)\to H_k(X)$ is injective. One way to do so is by fitting it into this exact sequence: $0\to H_k(A)\overset{i_*}{\to}H_k(X)$. Since the map from 0 is trivial, so is the kernel of $i_*$ by exactness of the sequence. That is all there is to it. Just think of the original long exact sequence as a way to encode information regarding $i_*,j_*,\partial$, and this new exact sequence as another way of encoding this information, given the additional condition that $i_*$ is injective.